# Conditional AMPscript required

Tags: salesforce-marketing-cloud, ampscript

I need a simple bit of AMPscript to serve up one type of email salutation where the First Name exists in the database and one where I don't.

So, IF Firstname is null: "Hello," - IF Firstname is not null: "Dear @Firstname"

Embarrassingly, everything I've tried hasn't worked.  I'm aware that this is a painfully simple bit of AMPscript

Comment: You'll get a lot more eyes on your SFMC questions over at [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com), specifically with the [marketing-cloud](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud) and [ampscript](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ampscript) tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
%%[

var @firstName
set @firstName = AttributeValue("firstName")

]%%

<!-- some other HTML -->

%%=iif(empty(@firstName),"Hello", concat("Dear ", propercase(@firstName)))=%%,
```

**Reference:**

- [attributevalue](https://ampscript.guide/attributevalue)
- [iif](https://ampscript.guide/iif)
- [empty](https://ampscript.guide/empty)
- [concat](https://ampscript.guide/concat)
- [propercase](https://ampscript.guide/propercase)